# how to use useSelector in typescript

Tags: typescript, redux

this is my code useSelector

```
const  user  = useSelector<RootStateOrAny, typeof typeRootReducer>((state) => state.user)
```

in rootReducer

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: userReducer
})


export default rootReducer
export type typeRootReducer =  ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

initState

```
const initState = {
    user: null
}
```

when I trying to `console.log(user.user.name)` it just give me `cannot read property name of null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your `user` is - as you wrote yourself - `null`. So you are calling `null.name`, which does not work. Nothing wrong with your selector usage per se, just your state contains something that does not match your code.

Generally, to avoid all the type gymnastics you are doing there, it is recommended to create a `useAppSelector` pre-typed hook, so you can just do
`const user = useAppSelector(state => state.user)` and everything will be typed correctly automatically.

Follow the [TypeScript Quick Start](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript) tutorial for that.